# Cycle through multiple possible credentials TCL Expect

Tags: ssh, tcl, expect, credentials, cisco

I wrote a script to login via ssh and run some commands. Half of the devices on list my device list have a different acceptable username and password combination.

I want expect to be able to interpret the failed login, start a new login attempt with the same device, but use different login credentials on the second attempt (there are two possible username and password combinations)

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it. This is my first time using TCL or expect.

A condensed version of what I have so far is below.

```
set username "someusername"
set password "somepassword"

set devices "X.X.X.X"

foreach device $devices {
    puts "Processing device: $device";
    spawn plink  -ssh $devices 

    expect "Store key in cache"
    send "y\r"

    expect "login as:"
    send "$username\r"

    expect "password:"
    send "$password\r"
    expect "#"

send "conf t\r"
expect "(config)#"

send "some commands\r"
expect "(config)#"

send "end\r"
expect "#"

send "copy run startup-config\r"
expect "#"
```

Comment: Did you know that `foreach` can iterate over two or more lists at once? `foreach device $devices username $usernames password $passwords {…}`. This can make this sort of thing easier…

Comment: I did NOT know that Donal. Thanks!  I think though that even if the foreach  had more than one list, TCL would quit after the first failed attempt. Moreover, the Cisco devices I am connected to do not re-prompt for the username  after the wrong password is entered so I think in addition to being able to pass more than one set of auth variables, the script would need to be able to start a new session using the same $device from $devices.  I'm not sure this is the case, just my guess. If, not i'm happy to be set straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need something like

```
set usernames [list name1 name2]
set passwords [list pw1   pw2  ]

set devices [list X.X.X.X ...]

foreach device $devices {
    puts "Processing device: $device";
    spawn plink  -ssh $devices 

    set auth_idx -1

    expect {
        "Store key in cache" {send "y\r"; exp_continue}

        "login as:" {
            incr auth_idx
            if {$auth_idx == [llength $usernames]} {
                puts "login failed for $device"

                # close the plink connection. I'm guessing here
                send \003       ;# Ctrl-C
                expect eof

                # and on to the next device
                continue
            }

            send "[lindex $usernames $auth_idx]\r"
            expect "password:"
            send "[lindex $passwords $auth_idx]\r"

            # and wait for either the command prompt or another login prompt
            exp_continue
        }

        "#"
    }

    # ... whatever you do when you're logged in

    # and logout. something like
    send "quit\r"
    expect eof
}
```

This uses `exp_continue` to "loop" within the same expect statement. I assume that you may not always have to store the key in the cache. I also assume that you see "login as" if the first login attempt fails

---

*UPDATE*

```
set usernames [list name1 name2]
set passwords [list pw1   pw2  ]

set devices [list X.X.X.X ...]

set device_idx 0
set auth_idx 0

while {$device_idx < [llength $devices]} {
    set device [lindex $devices $device_idx]

    puts "Processing device: $device";
    spawn plink  -ssh $devices 

    expect {
        "Store key in cache" {send "y\r"; exp_continue}

        "login as:" {
            send "[lindex $usernames $auth_idx]\r"
            expect "password:"
            send "[lindex $passwords $auth_idx]\r"
            exp_continue
        }

        "Access denied" {
            incr auth_idx
            if {$auth_idx == [llength $usernames]} {
                puts "login failed for $device"
                # next device
                set auth_idx 0
                incr device_idx
            } else {
                # close the plink connection. I'm guessing here
                send \003       ;# Ctrl-C
                expect eof
                # re-do with current device
            }
            continue
        }

        "#"
    }

    # ... whatever you do when you're logged in

    # and logout. something like
    send "quit\r"
    expect eof

    # and on to the next device
    set auth_idx 0
    incr device_idx
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post Glenn. Great stuff.! That "incr auth_inx" functionality looks to be a big part of what I need.  If the first login fails can we spawn a new session then apply the second set of creds? I ask because the target device will not go back to the beginning of the login prompts, it will just keep asking for the password for the username that was initially entered and there are two different usernames.
I.E
'login as: somepass
someuser@somedevice's password:
Access denied
someuser@somedevice's password:
Access denied
someuser@somedevice's password:

Comment: @glenjackman Your solution works great! However, now there is another variable popping up and that is the "Connection timed out" response (when the target host is not reachable) Can I add an "else if" or something to account for that?

Comment: See how I check for "store key"? Add another `pattern {condition} ` pair into the expect command